# PHP - put website frontend only in maintainance mode (.htaccess)

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, web

Is their a way to put website frontend only in Maintenance mode, and allow all users to access admin. (i am working on PHP).

I believe that can be done via .htaccess, but not getting how ?

Any help ?

I tried :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^admin/.*$ - [F]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This does the reverse work, I am able to access frontend and not admin with this code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to achieve this through .htaccess. At least not as a permanent solution. You could block access to edit pages but you will have to constantly edit .htaccess. Also you will have to make sure that you have all the paths right.

Magento has a builtin function to block editing. If it doesn't do what you want you should look into some magento plugins or create one yourself.

Also your question is a too broad. You should provide at least an example of what you have tried and explain what doesn't work.

Comment: Hi, I have modified what I have tried, with that code my admin is blocked but I am able to access frontend

Comment: I dont need to achieve a permanent solution, I can use Magento2 IP whitelist way, but we actually dont know the IP's , so we need to do this for all IPs

Comment: RewriteRule ^admin/.*$ - [F] returns a 403 - Forbidden status for the request: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_f
Why aren't you using the Magentos built-in maintenance mode?

Comment: Also, what do you mean to put only the front-end in maintenance mode? Maintenance mode is meant to be used when you want to apply some updates or changes. So that your users can't update content while you do that. Allowing edits while updating may break your website completely.

Comment: Actually my frontend is on maintenance mode, but admin want to see old orders

Comment: I think it would be the best to achieve this using a Magento plugin. This one seems good: https://marketplace.magento.com/folio3ecommerce-folio3-maintenancemode.html

Comment: If you still want to achieve this using the .htaccess you can enable htpassword access: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/htpasswd.html

Answer (score 0):

Any petition to an URL not containing 'admin' will redirect to index.php. Add some message "under maintenance" and you're done:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !admin/
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution. It will put in maintenance for clients but you can add users ips to access admin and fronted.

Edit index.php add this lines:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$allowed = array('your ip','second ip', 'third ip');
```

Change line

```
if (file_exists($maintenanceFile)) {
```

to

```
 if (file_exists($maintenanceFile) && !in_array($ip, $allowed)) {
```

Solution from:
http://inchoo.net/magento/maintenance-mode-in-magento/